# How can I create a register endpoint with client_id and client_Secret of oauth2 in djangorestframework?

Tags: oauth-2.0, django-rest-framework

I want to protect my registration api and hence use client_id and client_secret(created by oauth2 application) during the registration process also.
How can I do this?

Here is my view for registration

```
class RegisterUserView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    """
    POST auth/register/
    """
    serializer_class = UserRegistrationSerializer

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        username = request.data.get("username", "")
        password = request.data.get("password", "")
        email = request.data.get("email", "")
        if not username and not password and not email:
            return Response(
                data={
                    "message": "username, password and email is required to register a user"
                },
                status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST
            )
        new_user = User.objects.create_user(
            username=username, password=password, email=email
        )
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

Comment: If your api is public, I guess everyone can access the registration api as you have set permission as 'AllowAny'. If this isn't the case please elaborate the problem.

Comment: Sorry my bad! I will remove the permission class.
I want to make my registration api protected using client_id and client_secret i.e even the new user should have the client_id and client_secret

Comment: By protected do you mean - No one should be able to access this api ? or this api should be accessible only when client_id and client_secret is received ?

Comment: api should be accessed only when the client_id and client_secret is received

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this api should only be accessed when a client_id and client_secret is received then you can try the following two methods -

> 1. Make a custom permission. This is the right way to do it. Link - https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#custom-permissions
> 2. Check for the id and secret in apiview. This would be the easy way out.
>      For the following example I am considering you are sending the client_id and client_secret in request headers

```
class RegisterUserView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    """
    POST auth/register/
    """
    serializer_class = UserRegistrationSerializer

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        if((request.headers['Client-Id'] != client_id) or (request.headers['Client-Secret'] != client_secret):
            return Response(
                data={
                    "message": "Wrong Client id or Client Secret"
                },
                status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST
            )


        username = request.data.get("username", "")
        password = request.data.get("password", "")
        email = request.data.get("email", "")
        if not username and not password and not email:
            return Response(
                data={
                    "message": "username, password and email is required to register a user"
                },
                status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST
            )
        new_user = User.objects.create_user(
            username=username, password=password, email=email
        )
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

Comment: In headers the data key becomes capitialized. So try Client-Id and Client-Secret